# Unable to redirect error to a file in docker using bashscript

Tags: linux, docker

I am trying to test how to redirect errors for docker and I keep getting an empty error output.

Here is my bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo docker run --name test5 -e MyVar="test" hello-world -arg 2 >error
```

[image: empy error file]

Thanks so much!!

Comment: Use `2> error`. It's not valid to have a space between the `2` and the `>`

Answer (score 0):

As @thatotherguy noted correctly you can put a space after the `>` sign but not before it like so:

`du -sh /* 2> errfile` or `du -sh /* 2>errfile`

Comment: @lipo if this answer helped you please accept it

Answer (score 0):

> `sudo docker run --name test5 -e MyVar="test" hello-world -arg 2 >error`

I think you need to use `2>` and not `2 >`, which is a completely different thing.  The first is a token indicating redirection of standard error, while the second means an extra `"2"` parameter in the command line, followed by a redirection of *standard output*.